# How to use css costomproperties in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I need to use css costomproperties in lightning Aura component like so

`:colors{--Color1:color: #95ccff;} .line{color:var(--Color1);}`

I tried to use it in 'STYLE' at component bundle, but I got error.

Is it possible to use costomproperties in Aura?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Aura, we use [Tokens](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_intro.htm) instead. First, you create a [Token Bundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_bundles.htm), then you use the token function to access those values. For example, you would define a token bundle:

```
<aura:tokens>
  <aura:token name="Color1" value="#95ccff" />
</aura:tokens>
```

Then, in components that use the bundle:

```
.line { color: token(Color1) }
```

CSS custom properties, the standard, is not supported in Aura Components.

Comment: +1yes right!...

Comment: I succseeded. Thx a lot,